# Kotlin code to check if string contains any of words from array

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I have writtent following code to check if string contains any of of the words.

```
fun String.isValidUrl(): Boolean {
    return contains("http://") || contains("https://") || contains("www.")
}
```

How can I simplify this statement in kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you may want to use [`startsWith()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/starts-with.html) rather than `contains()`. Or it might not detect invalid URLs like, say, `abc://www.example.com`

You can use this:

```
val prefixes = arrayOf("http://", "https://", "www.")

fun String.isValidUrl() = prefixes.any { this.startsWith(it) }
```

**OR**

Use Android's built-in [`URLUtil.isValidUrl()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil#isValidUrl(java.lang.String))